# d3 with Angular 2 - cannot read property 'style' of null

Tags: javascript, angularjs, d3.js

I'm trying to use d3.js with Angular 2. I have my d3 stuff in it's own directive:

```
import * as angular from '@angular/core';
import { Directive, OnChanges, OnInit, ViewContainerRef, Attribute } from '@angular/core';
import { Inject } from '@angular/core';
import * as d3 from 'd3/d3';

@Directive({
    selector: 'life-cycle-visual',
    properties: ['data']
})

export class LifeCycleVisual implements OnChanges {

    public data: number[];
    public divs: any;

    constructor(
        @Inject(ViewContainerRef) viewContainerRef: ViewContainerRef,
        @Attribute('width') width: string,
        @Attribute('height') height: string) {

        var el:any    = viewContainerRef.element.nativeElement;
        var graph:any = d3.select(el);
        console.log(graph);

        this.divs = graph.
              append('div').
              attr({
                'class': 'chart'
              }).
              style({
                'width':  width  + 'px',
                'height': height + 'px',
              }).
              selectAll('div');
    }

    render(newValue) {
    if (!newValue) return;

    this.divs.data(newValue).enter().append('div')
      .transition().ease('elastic')
      .style('width', d => d + '%')
      .text(d => d + '%');

  }

  onChanges() {
    this.render(this.data);
  }
}
```

and I'm getting this error in the console:

```
TypeError: Cannot read property 'style' of null
```

Now the `console.log` ensures me that the `graph` variable is fine and that d3 is correctly selecting the element, but for some reason I still get this error.

Any ideas?

Comment: Tough to troubleshoot from the code above, anyway you can put together a reproducible example on plunker?

Comment: @Mark sure: http://plnkr.co/edit/20qedkAj1AR7AWANkEZW. thanks!

Comment: Am I missing something?  Even after fixing the `d3` loading, your plunker doesn't do anything? http://plnkr.co/edit/JFlnBKybib14CIeoJzf3?p=preview

Comment: @Mark thanks for fixing that stuff - never used plunkr before. It's just showing me the `<h1 class="title">Angular 2 + d3</h1>` part of the template but not the d3 component part.

Comment: Should be `directives: [LifeCycleVisual]` not `directive: [LifeCycleVisual]`...

Comment: @Mark ahh yeah - thanks. Is the chart showing for you now? Still doesn't show for me :(

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/116407/discussion-between-taimur-and-mark).

Comment: What was the outcome here?